# Can't understand this condition

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I don't understand the condition `((wins[i] & score) === wins[i])`. `score` is a value and `wins[i]` is an element inside an array that contains integers. They are compared like if they were booleans. Enlighten me please.

```
wins = [7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84];

win = function (score) { //score is an int value
    for (var i = 0; i < wins.length; i += 1) {
        if ((wins[i] & score) === wins[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've asked around and people talking about bitwise operators. Could someone explain the condition as simple as possible? I understand "normal" logical operator.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: _'I understand "normal" logical operator.'_ - As an aside, note that JavaScript's logical operators `||` and `&&` can be used on non-boolean operands (in which case they don't even return a boolean).

Comment: @nnnnnn It's not about logical operators here.

Comment: @dystroy - That's why I said "as an aside" and explicitly typed out the operators I meant. The OP said "compared like if they were booleans", which made me wonder if maybe he or she didn't really know how the logical operators work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't logical operators, they are fundamentally different. You need to understand the binary representation of numbers. So for example, if `a = 7` and `b = 12`, then `a & b` is evaluated by looking at the bits which are 1 in both `a` **and** `b`:

```
  a 00000111
  b 00001100
a&b 00000100
```

So `7 & 12 = 4`. Similarly, `|` is a bitwise rather than a logical or.

Answer (score 0):

People talking about bitwise operators are right: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation
In this case, the entire condition is true, if `win[i]` contains no binary 1 at a position, where `score` doesn't also have a binary 1. (in other words, bitwise implication `win[i]` => `score`)

Comment: So e.g if win[i] = 101010 and score = 010101 the conditions is true? Also how does the true condition === to win[i]. === is a simple comparison logical operator.

Comment: no that is a counterexample since score contains zeroes, where win[i] contains ones! the `===` operator isn't special here, it really just checks equality of the two integers ;)

Answer (score 0):

We can't completely answer here, as we don't have the context.

You must understand that it's about the binary representation of the integers, which are used as bit storage.

You can see the bits using

```
[7, 56, 448, 73, 146, 292, 273, 84].map(function(v) { var s=v.toString(2);return '00000000'.slice(s.length)+s })
```

which returns

```
["00000111", "00111000", "111000000", "01001001", "10010010", "100100100", "100010001", "01010100"]
```

The `win` function returns `true` when you pass a `score` whose binary representation has `1` everywhere some `wins[i]` value has `1`. So your `score` must have at least those bits filled.

For example the score whose binary value is `10000111` (135) is OK as the `10000111 & 00000111` is `00000111`.